# <video> sem som no iOS

Tags: html5, ios, apache-cordova, html5-video

Estou utilizando a tag video do html 5, mas quando executada em um iOS (um app utilizando o phonegap) não há som, o que pode ser?

Segui exatamente o exemplo utilizado pelo W3SChools e mesmo assim não há som.

Código:

```
<div class="midia">
    <video id="video" controls preload="auto" autobuffer style="border-radius:1em;">
       <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: É bem possível que o problema seja no Safari. Se a versão for muito antiga ele não reconhece/dá pau nas tags HTML5. Tem como testar de outra forma?

Comment: eu fiz os testes no navegador Opera, funciona normalmente, acho que o problema está no safari mesmo